# MS c++ app, problem in Release mode but not Debug

Tags: c++, winapi

Using VS2022, I created a c++ (ver 14) console app.  This app needs to have no UI or console window, which is working.  In order to implement no UI or console window, I changed the default 'Main' to
**int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int cmdShow)** However, I'm having issues when switching to Release mode, which I could use some assistance with.

The first problem is a link error, when I change to Release mode, **LNK2001 'unresolved external symbol _main**.  A google search I found suggested adding back the default **int main(int argc, char** argv)**, in addition to the wWinMain.  This did allow for a successful compile/build.  The issue is, in debug mode, the entry point is wWinMain, in Release mode, the entry point is main(...).  I'm not sure why this is occurring or how to go about fixing it.  Help is appreciated.

I'm unable to run the app in Release mode but I am in Debug mode.

Comment: _"In order to implement no UI or console window ..."_ what else are you using then?

Comment: Check your project settings to make sure that you've changed the entry point. Under Linker -> Advanced

Comment: Your settings will dictate which one of  `int main()` or `wWinMain()` are required. Also remember that each configuration Release, Debug... has separate settings so when you change a setting its not applied to a different configuration unless you told it to apply to multiple configurations or all.

Comment: It sounds like you only changed the entry point in your `Debug` config, Take a look at the option, Select the `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Advanced property page`. Modify the `Entry Point` property. You need to change BOTH, the Releases and Debug config.

Comment: The solution you followed was wrong. What determines the user-provided entry point is the `/SUBSYSTEM` linker setting. Switch it to `WINDOWS` (for *all* configurations), and you can remove the `main` entry point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are lots of ways to communicate with a program that has neither a GUI nor a console (e.g. pipes, mailslots, events, plus lots of other [IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) options). If you're curious, ask a question.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.  Changing my subsystem for release to Console and setting the EntryPoint to mainCRTStartup have fixed my issues

Answer (score 0):

As comments pointed out, [/SUBSYSTEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-170) specifies the Windows subsystem targeted by the executable. You can [set this linker option in the Visual Studio development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-170#to-set-this-linker-option-in-the-visual-studio-development-environment).

> The **`/SUBSYSTEM`** option specifies the environment for the executable.
>
> The choice of subsystem affects the entry point symbol (or entry point
> function) that the linker will select.

[image]